# Chartjs: How to set the maximum number of ticks on a logarithmic scale

Tags: javascript, chart.js, logarithm

I have a graph in chartjs whose Y-Axis uses a logarithmic scale. I want to set the max ticks limit property but it doesn't seem to do anything for scales using logarithmic.

```
yAxes: [{
        type: 'logarithmic',
        ticks: {
             callback: function (value, index, values) { //used to change the labels from scientific notation to integers
                   return Number(value.toString());
             },
             maxTicksLimit: 5
        }
        
}]
```

This method works for my non logarithmic charts, is there another way to accomplish this for charts using logarithmic?

Comment: have you figured out?